# How do you format the current time stamp for hour and minute in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How do you configure the MySQL time stamp to be in HH:MM only?

If I was wanting to specially format it another way, how would I do that also?

Specifically the database table (ALTER) configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) functionality

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i')
```

Comment: But how do you do the mysql DB configuration?

Comment: The closest fieldtype in mysql is the 'TIME' type, which also includes the seconds. If you want to do something like `SELECT * FROM table` and have it only return the HOURS:MINUTES portion of the time field, you'll need to use a view.

Comment: so you can't configure it for the future?